# chart in $refs cannot be referenced

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a working `vue-chartjs`.
When trying to optimize it, I got in a situation regarding `$refs`.

To conextualize, I get some external data and update the chart `ref="myChart"`.

calling:

```
this.$refs.myChart.chart.update();
```

works fine.

However, if:

```
this.chart = this.$refs.myChart.chart;
this.chart.update();
```

I get an *Stack Overflow (tm)* error:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at addScopesFromKey (helpers.segment.mjs:1883:10)
    at createSubResolver (helpers.segment.mjs:1875:11)
    at _resolveWithPrefixes (helpers.segment.mjs:1906:11)
    at helpers.segment.mjs:1717:15
    at _cached (helpers.segment.mjs:1798:17)
    at Object.get (helpers.segment.mjs:1716:14)
    at _resolveWithContext (helpers.segment.mjs:1804:15)
    at helpers.segment.mjs:1758:15
    at _cached (helpers.segment.mjs:1798:17)
    at Object.get (helpers.segment.mjs:1757:14)
```

What I highly suspect is that this might be some vue.js Proxy/voodoo which breaks when copying object references.  Or maybe not, maybe only some chart.js way to handle this.

So, What I am asking is not really how to fix my code (it is fine), but to understand what it is going on here.

For example, how does ES6 knows that when calling from `this.chart` instead `this.$refs.myChart.chart` is not the same thing, as it is supposed to handle the same reference.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I'd expect that this.chart is reactive and so it messes with original object, but there should be no place for guesswork

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware about `Proxy`.
My previous contact with javascript was before ES6 was out.

So a `Proxy::get()` could explain what was going on.